# Excel if text string contains todays date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

A colleague of mine is trying to come up with a formula to see if a text string contains today's date, so it would be something like

```
=IF(A1=TODAY(),1,0)
```

Except the date is contained in a text string, not just on it's own, so like

```
=IF(A1="TODAY()",1,0)
```

Though of course that doesn't work. Essentially it's how can you place wildcards on the side of a formula like that to make it work?

Comment: Are you looking for TODAY() in a string concatenation or today's date (e.g. 05-Jul-2017) as part of a string?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`SEARCH`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/SEARCH-SEARCHB-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495) function to search a string for a substring. Alternatively you can use the [`FIND`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-FINDB-functions-C7912941-AF2A-4BDF-A553-D0D89B0A0628) function however this is case-sensitive.

The issue you're going to face is that the [`TODAY()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TODAY-function-5EB3078D-A82C-4736-8930-2F51A028FDD9) function actually outputs a serial number, not a formatted date so you will need to first format this number within the formula using the [`TEXT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-20D5AC4D-7B94-49FD-BB38-93D29371225C) function (provided you know what format the date will be in). You can then use [`ISNUMBER`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/IS-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665) to check whether the `SEARCH` function returns a hit, like this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TEXT(TODAY(),"dd/mm/yyyy"), A1)),1,0)
```

This will only work if you know the format of the date.

If the date could be in multiple different formats you could combine these together with an `OR` statement to check the different formats like this:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TEXT(TODAY(),"dd/mm/yyyy"), A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TEXT(TODAY(),"dd/mm/yy"), A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TEXT(TODAY(),"d/m/yy"), A1))),1,0)
```